# Check if different user has read/write permissions to a file on linux

Tags: linux, file-permissions, audit

How can I check if a specific user with no shell assigned can write or read a file ?

As an example we can use apache user... is there any option in touch or any other commands?

Thanks

Answer (score 29):

The "test" command is designed for this use case.

```
sudo -u otheruser test -r /path/to/file
```

will return 0 if otheruser can read the file, or 1 if otheruser cannot read the file. You can run `test -r /path/to/file; echo "$?"` to view the return code of the `test` command.

Use `test -w` to test for write permission and `test -x` to test for execute permission.

Answer (score 7):

### Test Read Permission

Attempt to read the beginning of the file and discard the normal output. You can then look for an empty string (success) or a "Permission denied" message (you can also check for other error messages such as "No such file or directory").  For example:

```
head -1 /path/to/file 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep 'Permission denied'
```

### Test Write Permission

Use the touch command with the -c (--no-create) option.  Combine stdout and stderr and again search for an empty string (success) or an error:

```
touch -c /path/to/file 2>&1 | grep 'Permission denied'
```

If you're explicitly testing write access of a directory, be sure to test the directory and not a file contained within, since with the -c option, there's no error condition if the file doesn't exist even in a directory you don't have write access to:

From [Wikipedia: touch (Unix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_%28Unix%29)

> -c, if the file does not exist, do not create it and do not report this condition

### Test As Specific User

The final piece of the puzzle is how to check this as a different user.  As root execute the test command as the desired user with "sudo -u *[username]* *[command]*" so using your suggested user:

```
sudo -u apache touch -c /path/to/file 2>&1
```

Comment: What if you don't have root permissions for sudo?

Comment: Good point - question was how to check for permissions on *a specific* user, so it's not a stretch to assume "checker" has root.  If I, as a non-root user, want to know permissions/access of another user, I can't see a clear way to do that without asking a) a sysadmin or b) the user....

Comment: Yes, this was something I wanted to do without root, and we couldn't find a solution...

Comment: @Siwel What if you started by looking at the permissions and user/group ownership of the specific directory, then compare that against the user you're interested in?  So if a directory is userA:groupA - with perms drwxrwxr-x, and userB isn't in groupA, then no.